# Clear the Android Billing local cache?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am using the Android Billing API V3 for querying purchase information from the play store. I am wondering if it is possible to clear the local cache.

V3 added the local caching feature for the billing API to cut down on network traffic. I have an update service which is run daily which updates my metadata and since I display the costs in my application I wish to flush the local cache and trigger an update in case I have updated prices to ensure the correct price is shown.

**Documentation says:**

*Because the Google Play client now caches In-app Billing information locally on the device, you can use the Version 3 API to query for this information more frequently, for example through a getPurchases call. Unlike with previous versions of the API, many Version 3 API calls will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network connection to Google Play, which significantly speeds up the API's response time.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the Google Play client is app doing the caching, and there is not an API exposed to clear the cache.

I don't see why you want to clear the cache though? The Google Play client is notified of any changes, so would invalidate it's cache accordingly. Just assume the calls returned are correct.

Comment: Given that there are no controls exposed for the service I think you're right and I will just have to assume that the call will always be correct. Cheers

Comment: I managed to delete previous purchases by 1- manually cancelling the transactions in Google Checkout, and then 2- clearing Google Play Store's data (not cache).

Comment: I've been trying to invalidate the cache just because in-app billing purchases seems to not be syncing across devices instantly (I buy on one, go to other device, and the Google Play Services response seems to be cached as the item is still not purchased). I found other questions related, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306263/android-in-app-purchases-not-syncing-immediately-across-multiple-devices , but didn't find any correct answers yet...

Comment: As well I notices, that sometimes Google Play client doesn't  invalidate cache too long, for example: I created three subscriptions, one of them i firstly saved as inactive, and then saved as active. And two other I saved as active in a first place. Google Play has been returning only two subs for about two hours, then I clear cache of google play app, and only after I got returned all 3 subs from google play.

Answer (score 1):

You must know that the android in app purchase one time purchases are allow only one time in the lifetime for one user. you want it again you have to make a request or create a new product in play console. for more go to this link.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime

Comment: ya but i put a solution for someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Add this `Application` class :

```
package com.hrupin.cleaner;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Then, Make this call from any `Activity`:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().clearApplicationData();
```

Reference :

[How to Clear User Data in your Android Application programmatically](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I apologize that I haven't had a chance to do anything with it yet. I am blocked on this task due to a configuration issue with my developer account. I do not think that the billing API cache will be under my application cache as I suspect it will be cross all applications, given the nature of integrating with the play billing API (firing intents to their service which runs outside of my application scope)

Comment: Actually, it's not a ridiculous suggestion that Google Play might cache each app's related inventory items in the app's own data store.