# Android In App purchases not syncing immediately across multiple devices

Tags: android, google-play-services

I purchased an item on one device. Then I go to the other device, launch the App, but the item's purchase information is still not available for use on the second device (iabhelper does not return the item when you query the inventory). Attempting to purchase just shows the "Already owned" dialog. (I could possibly use this as a point to go ahead and download the item, but feels weird...)

The only solution that works so far is if I restart the device, then I immediately see the Download option in my UI (instead of Buy), since Iabhelper then returns the correct info)

Anybody else face this issue? Is there a workaround which makes it seamless to the user?

Comment: asim, did you find a solution for this besides a restart? With my brand new app a customer report very the same problem... (haven't test the restart workaround yet)

Comment: Restart is the only solution so far

Comment: I think this is by design. They assume that when you buy an item on a device, you will use it on that device, and not go use it immediately on a different one. This way, servers can take their time to propagate purchase updates.

Comment: According to the documentation you can check the state of an item before displaying the buy dialog. That way you can check the state of the item. http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getBuyIntent

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure but Google Play Services are most probably using their data storage, which has eventual consistency, and that means that not everything is synchronized right away. Just a guess.
You can try clearing the Google play services cache, but I'm guessing that it is as annoying as restarting the device.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to program it yourself utilising `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`
[as in seen in billing reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)