# In App Billing V3: Syncing purchases across devices

Tags: java, android, android-billing

Using In app billing V3, I notice that if I purchase an item on a device, and then immediately run a `getPurchases` call on another device, my list of purchases is not tested. Upon further testing, I've revealed that either rebooting the device or clearing cache in the Google Play app causes the purchases to be refreshed.

Is this a bug in In app billing V3 that we have to live with, or are there any workarounds so that the local in app billing cache will get updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the inventory is eventually consistent after a few hours. It's rather by design than a bug.

Rebooting the device or clearing cache of the Google Play services triggers the changes to propagate immediately. I think there's no programmatic workaround for this.

Comment: agreed, do you have any evidence that this is by design? I haven't seen anything in the docs.

Comment: @stevebot Check the accepted answer (posted by Googler) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354475/clear-the-android-billing-local-cache?rq=1

Comment: thanks, but that does not indicate what the SLA is. I have emailed Google myself and have yet to get a straight answer.

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer, based on my experience since then. IT's unfortunate that Google does not officially state this anywhere obvious, as it can cause confusion for users and developers.